# How to use a npm package as a maven dependency?

Tags: maven, npm

I want to use a npm package in a java maven project.

It's just one file that is used in the java project.

We have two projects.

1. react frontend project where a bundle.js is the artifact which is uploaded with maven
2. java maven project where we use the bundle.js as a maven dependency

Now we want to get rid of the maven stuff in the react project.

So we will upload the bundle.js as a npm package into our npm registry.

We use nexus3 for our npm and maven repositories.

I want to avoid adding a maven plugin in the java project to install the npm package with a real npm installation.

Maybe there is kind of a npm maven proxy plugin for maven or a npm maven proxy possibility in nexus3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is fresh maven plugin to do such operations like obtaining resources from NPM, filtering and packing into JAR:WAR: https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM

Sample for pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.orienteer.jnpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packages>
                    <package>vue@2.6.11</package>
                    <package>vuex@~3.4.0</package>
                </packages>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: As of this writing, jnpm-maven-plugin isn't on maven central. Which repository to use?

Comment: Yes - there was such problem with publication. Version 1.1 is indeed already on central. Please check issue https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM/issues/5 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

We now solved this with a modified version of the following maven [plugin](https://github.com/adierkens/npm-maven-plugin/commit/a4b7cdbbba868c86682784d20403d67d033f6a0c) .

This allows us to use our private npm registry with basic authentification.

With the plugin we are able to download the npm packages in the java project to the target dir:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.javascript</groupId>
    <artifactId>npm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>fetch-modules</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/npmpackages</outputDirectory>
                <npmRepositoryBase>${npm.repositoryUrl}</npmRepositoryBase>
                <username>${npm.username}</username>
                <password>${npm.password}</password>
                <packages>
                    <package>ourfont:1.0.1</package>
                </packages>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Next we use the maven-resources-plugin to copy the file to the src dir in the same phase and overwrite it every time to ensure it's the correct version:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/fonts</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/npmpackages/ourfont</directory>
                        <include>ourfont.ttf</include>
                        <include>ourfont.svg</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The global config for the plugin is done in our maven-settings.xml which is available on every environment:

```
<profil>
    ...
    <properties>
        <npm.repositoryUrl>https://nexus......com/repository/npm-group/</npm.repositoryUrl>
        <npm.username>service.account@......com</npm.username>
        <npm.password>......</npm.password>
    </properties>
</profil>
```